# Multiple inputs in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to write a bash script to install mysql, automatically. There is a utility "mysql_secure_installation" that comes along with mysql. This can be run to secure the mysql installation. This is a shell script, this takes in multiple interactive inputs when called. How can i automatically pass these values to the script, with out actually modifying the utility script. I know about EOF markers, but I am not sure if i can use them here. Thanks in advance

This utility script asks a sequence of questions. If it is single prompt, I can use heredocs, but how can I pass inputs to subsequent prompts. This is how the execution looks like

```
venkatesh@venki-ws003:~/jit/jambuvaan-app$ mysql_secure_installation 




NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!


In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Setting the root password ensures that nobody can log into the MySQL
root user without the proper authorisation.

You already have a root password set, so you can safely answer 'n'.

Change the root password? [Y/n] n
 ... skipping.

By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone
to log into MySQL without having to have a user account created for
them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation
go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving into a
production environment.

Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from 'localhost'.  This
ensures that someone cannot guess at the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that anyone can
access.  This is also intended only for testing, and should be removed
before moving into a production environment.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] Y
 - Dropping test database...
ERROR 1008 (HY000) at line 1: Can't drop database 'test'; database doesn't exist
 ... Failed!  Not critical, keep moving...
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...
```

Comment: show some example code that you have tried !

Comment: @iamauser I have not tried anything, as I do not know how to do it. I also tried googling "multiple inputs in bash shell" but did not find anything useful. I wanna know if this possible or not, if possible how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an expect script you could use too:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 2 
set password ""

spawn mysql_secure_installation

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Enter current password for*"
}

send "$password\r"

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Set * password? *"
}

send "n\r"

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Remove anonymous users? *"
}

send "Y\r"

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Disallow root login remotely? *"
}

send "Y\r"

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Remove test database and access to it? *"
}

send "Y\r"

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Reload privilege tables now? *"
}

send "Y\r"

expect {
    timeout { exit 1; }
    "Cleaning up..."
}
```

Save it to a file in UNIX format and run `expect script.exp`.

Answer (score 0):

Those "EOF markers" are called [**heredocs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). And you can use them if the program/script gets its input from stdin (most do).

```
some_command << EOF
do this
do that
EOF
```